# Iterated function applied on $n/ \log_2 n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given a function $f(n) = n/\log_2 n$ I have to iteratively apply the
function towards its arguments.

I want get the min iteration times that let the result $\le$ 2

that is $$f^{(i)}(n) \le 2, \min (i) = ?$$

Comment: Is the $\log$ to base $2$?

Comment: Oh sorry! It's used in computer science, so I omit base 2. How about $\log_2$?

Comment: Don't know. Seems difficult. LambertW making an appearance.